# Integral of a polar equation $r=1+\cos\theta$ from limits $-\pi/2$ to $0$ does not give me the same value as integrating from $3\pi/2$ to $0$. Why?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, area, curves

To find the area of the cardioid (given by the polar equation $r=1+\cos(\theta)$)

I am trying to integrate a polar function ${r=1+\cos(\theta)}$, I do not have a problem with indefinite integration but if I were to integrate it from the limits $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ to $0$, I get the answer as: $\frac{\pi+2}{2}$

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^0 1+\cos(\theta)\ d\theta$$ $$=[\theta]^{0}_{-\pi/2}+[\sin(\theta)]^{0}_{-\pi/2}$$

$$=(0-(-\frac{\pi}{2}))+(\sin(0)-\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}))$$

$$=\frac{\pi+2}{2}$$
However, I have been assuming that if I were to integrate the same function from $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ to $0$, I would be getting the same as the previously obtained value (i.e. $\frac{\pi+2}{2}$). But this is not the case, I get a value of $-\frac{3\pi-2}{2}$:

$$\int_{3\pi/2}^0 1+\cos(\theta)\ d\theta$$

$$=[\theta]^{0}_{3\pi/2}+[\sin(\theta)]^{0}_{3\pi/2}$$

$$=(0-(\frac{3\pi}{2}))+(\sin(0)-\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}))$$

$$=-\frac{3\pi-2}{2}$$

Since the intervals of the angles $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ to $0$ is the same as $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ to $0$, then why are the definite integral values different?

Also, shouldn't the value obtained by the integral in between the intervals $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $0$ be negative? Because the interval lies in the 4th quadrant - meaning the area under the curve lies below the x-axis and thus should have negative area.

Is my reasoning wrong? Could someone please clear these doubts of mine?

Comment: Tip: Write `$\sin(\theta)$` for $\sin(\theta)$, etc.

Comment: You could go from $3\pi/2$ to $2\pi$ if you like, but $3 \pi/2$ to $0$ is not at all the same as $-\pi/2$ to $0$.

Comment: Integral from $\frac {3 \pi} 2$ to $0$ is minus of integral from $0$ to $\frac {3 \pi} 2$  and this involves the values of the integrand from $0$ to $\frac {3 \pi} 2$. There is no reason why this should be same as the integral from $-\frac {\pi} 2$ to $0$.

Comment: Also, that part about “area under the curve should be negative” seems to be a rather fundamental misunderstanding. It has absolutely nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: From the context, I would guess that “are” is a typo for “area” rather than “arc”.

Comment: @HansLundmark Well, area $= \frac{1}{2}\int r^2 d\theta$, which OP hasn't done...

Comment: @AdamRubinson: True!

Comment: If you're taking the integral from $\frac {3 \pi}{2} \rightarrow 0$, that is a large swing compared to $-\frac {\pi}{2} \rightarrow 0$, and as such accounts for the difference in your answers, despite being coterminal to each other.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I'm extremely sorry that I didn't take into account the actual formula for the area. Thank you very much for the clarification. 

Comment: @HansLundmark Oh! so going from 3pi/2 to 0 would take me in the clock wise direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_{3\pi/2}^0 [1+\cos(\theta)]]^2 d\theta=-\frac{3\pi-2}{2}$$

$$\int^{3\pi/2}_0 [1+\cos(\theta)]^2 d\theta=+\frac{3\pi-2}{2}$$

because when the upper and lower limits of the integral are interchanged then the evaluated definite integral value changes sign. This is because

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx =F(b)-F(a)\text{ and }\int_b^a f(x) dx =F(a)-F(b)$$

Also the two areas of cardioid between $ \theta$ limits [red $(0, 3\pi/2)$, blue $(3\pi/2, 4 \pi/2)$] are not equal.

[image]

Comment: +1 : nice graphics.

Comment: The area is $\frac{1}{2} \int r^2 d\theta,$ not $\int r d\theta.$

Comment: Thanks, corrected typo.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, area is never negative.

Secondly, $\displaystyle\int_{x=x_1}^{x=x_2} y(x) dx$ gives a negative value if and only if the total area below the $x-$axis is greater than the total area above the $x-$axis. In fact, the above integral is precisely equal to the area above the $x-$axis minus the area below the $x-$axis. But the point is that this is about $\int y(x) dx,$ not area or polar coordinates.

In polar coordinates, when finding area you don't usually need to think about "above" and "below" $x-$axis, because you are finding area, which is always positive anyway.

Thirdly, in polar coordinates, the area of a region bounded by two lines $\theta=\theta_1$ and $\theta=\theta_2$ and a curve $r=f(\theta),\ $ is $\quad\frac{1}{2} \displaystyle\int_{\theta=\theta_1}^{\theta=\theta_2} r^2 d\theta,\ $ and not $\quad\displaystyle\int_{\theta=\theta_1}^{\theta=\theta_2} r d\theta.$ If you apply this to your question you will find that $\quad\frac{1}{2} \displaystyle\int_{\theta=-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta=0} (1+\cos(\theta))^2 d\theta = \quad\frac{1}{2} \displaystyle\int_{\theta=\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{\theta=2\pi} (1+\cos(\theta))^2 d\theta. $

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification sir, I didn't take into account the formula for the area under a polar curve.

Comment: I am sorry I am not able to upvote your answer since I'm new to this forum and I require a few 'reputation points' in order to upvote. But thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @SuhasBharadwaj When you do get enough reputation, feel free to come back and upvote if you want to lol